# Javascript Switch statement with map that adds X amount of cases

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am fetching a unknown amount of images, I want to create a function that maps through the array of images, and depending on the case of the switch it decides the image it displays

Ive tried inserting a map function containing a case inside a switch, but i get an error saying i need a case

```
switch(this.state.currentImage){
   user.photos.map((img, index) => {
        return (
                <Image 
                style={[styles.photo, {zIndex: 5, flexDirection: "row"}]} 
                source={{ uri: img }}/>
               )
        }
}
```

Comment: unclear how the switch works with what is provided. Where is the `case`

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough context to give you an absolute answer.
And I don't think you understand how a switch works. A switch tests if the condition in the cases are the same as in the in switch.

```
switch ('Test') {
  case 'Test':
   console.log('This will be logged');
   break;
  case 'Wrongtest':
   console.log('This will not');
   break;
}
```

But if the images is stored in an array, and you want to only use a few depending on some variable or data, I would approach it like this:

```
let allImages = [img1, img2, img3, img4 ...];
let imagesToShow = [];
function parseImages(){
allImages.forEach(image => {
  if (image.importantVariable){
    imagesToShow.push(image)
   }
 })
}
```

The if statement checks if the "important" thing in the image is what you want it to be. Since you did not state what is the deciding factor, I don't know what you would put in the if statement.
Then you can use the images in imagesToShow-array.